# Objects to pass in to a nested resources link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using nested resources don't know what objects to pass in to make the link go to the right place. I have 3 models posts, comments and questions, where comments belong to posts and questions belong to comments. I am trying to link from the posts index page to the questions index page.

This is what the routes.rb file looks like:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
 end
end

resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
 end
end
```

The link in the posts index file:

```
  <% post.comments.select(:body).order('created_at desc').limit(2).each do |comment| %>         

  <%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(comment, @question) %>
  <% end %>
```

This gives me this error:

```
missing required keys: [:comment_id]
```

Here are the results of 'rake routes | grep comment_question':

```
comment_questions GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions(.:format)   questions#index
comment_question GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions/:id(.:format) questions#show
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your view, because in order to get the object `comment` on an post index page you must be looping through for instance @posts.  It might be helpful to see those pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're linking to a single resource, the correct path should be something like:

```
comment_question_path(comment, @question)
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the comment_id explicity:

```
comment_question_path(comment.id, @question)
```

Also, if you could post the results of the `rake routes | grep comment_question` command, that would be helpful.

Edit:
As the second entry in your `rake routes` output displays, the path/url methods are expecting two arguments.

```
/comments/:comment_id/questions/:id(.:format)
```

The symbols translated into the path method look like this (the `:id` symbol is the question id):

```
comment_question_path(:comment_id, :id)
```

Based on the error message, it looks like comment is nil and it may be falling back to the next path in the URI (in this case `questions`).

Can you throw a debugger statement prior to that path usage and show the output of both `pp comment` and `pp @question`?

Comment: Hmm, both those are giving me a 'Couldn't find Comment with id=questions' error. I posted the rake routes | grep comment_question as a question edit.

Comment: Now i'm getting a 'Couldn't find Comment with id=comment_id' error. I wasn't able to correctly use 'pp(comment) through. The edit to my views may help (shows what's looping).

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to (comment.body), comment_questions_path(comment) %>
```

Comment: This gives me a 'Couldn't find Comment with id=questions' error.

Comment: can you check value of comment variable? Or what happens if you replace comment with comment.id?

Comment: That path is incorrect if you are looking specifically for the comments linked to a specific question. Assuming REST conventions are being followed, the index action would have all of the questions associated with a comment.

Comment: @MarekTakac comment.id gives me the same 'id=questions' error. I edited my question to show what i'm looping through in my view.